# What is PLACEIMPMACROHERE?

Tags: google-chrome, security

I've noticed calls coming from my PC to the url PLACEIMPMACROHERE when accessing certain websites in Chrome - usually after they've been open for awhile.

I also see when looking at Google that this is happening with many websites as they've created pages for it -- https://www.google.com/#q=placeimpmacrohere

What is PLACEIMPMACROHERE and is it something to worry about?

Comment: It doesn’t look good. It looks like that could potentially be part of some malware kit and people who use it forget to replace the variables. Is there any pattern to *which* websites this happens with? Have you tried disabling any third-party plugins and extensions (and of course restarting Chrome) to see if it still happens? *Where* did you see the calls coming from your system, a packet-sniffer?

Comment: I've seen no pattern other than it happened to be on sites that were open for some time.  I was doing some unrelated programming work last night and had fiddler running and chrome was open.. when I woke up I saw this unusual called filtered by PLACEIMPMACROHERE and noticed there were a handful of these calls overnight.. typed it into google and saw that tens of thousands of pages came up with PLACEIMPMACROHERE.  I have not seen it since.

Comment: Wow, you can't even look that up on Google without hitting all the sites who added it, to accommodate anyone who is searching it (which is useless). Only reference i [found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598605/deny-access-to-any-url-containing-certain-words) is someone who saw his site got hit by browser adding this and wanted to block it. It might be some malware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is very little information about this that I could find, other than what seems to be autogenerated URLs ([related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598605/deny-access-to-any-url-containing-certain-words)).

I found it mentioned [here](http://jsunpack.jeek.org/?report=fa3c64baa8bab190c68358b4c201dbcde4b010ec) though. The site allows viewing and downloading some JavaScript (I have no idea what it's for, actually) that includes the term `PLACEIMPMACROHERE` and appears to be related to the "Turn" advertising network. When I opened the URL mentioned on the site though, the script was completely different, so it's not a sure match.

I suggest you install Ghostery in your browser (which is probably a good idea anyway) and disable Turn ads to see whether that resolves the issue.

Comment: Amusing that the url is `bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs`. `:-D`

Comment: Thank you, I guess that was the pattern - those sites were running ads.  It must have been loading as some third party ads through Adsense displaying on those sites.